# How can I resolve hostname to ip using different DNS servers?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ip-address

For my task, I need to block some hostnames, but since some websites *may* reply with different IP addresses to different DNS queries (for example, Google DNS and any other DNS server), I'd like to resolve same hostname using different DNS servers to get as many possible IP addresses as possible.

Can I solve this task using command line utilities on Ubuntu 16+? Are there any alternative solutions?

In short: I'd like to resolve "example.com" to IP using DNS #A and resolve "example.com" to IP using DNS #B without making any serious changes to my network configuration.

Comment: `man host`, `man nslookup` or `man dig` - any of those should help

Comment: Have you considered how the client subnet DNS option can interfere with your results?

Comment: While this is not what you asked about, still it might be useful in the context. There are online services which query different DNS worldwide and give you a list of the answers - e.g. https://www.whatsmydns.net/ (I am not affiliated)

Comment: If you need to block a *hostname*, it may be easiest to set up your own DNS resolver and have it return a "NXDOMAIN" error whenever someone tries to look up the hostname in question.  I do this to reduce Facebook's tracking abilities.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can with the tools @pawel7318 mentioned.

### dig

```
dig @nameserver hostname
```

### nslookup

```
nslookup hostname nameserver
```

### host

```
host hostname nameserver
```

Comment: Just use `dig` and you can forget all the others.

Answer (score 3):

I believe

`nslookup -q= < record type > < host > < DNS server >`

will make the trick for you.